# How do I use <Ctrl+1> instead of <Ctrl+6> in VIM?

Tags: macos, command-line, open-source, vi

I have been searching for a while, but i still can't get it work.

I add `:map <C-6> <C-1>` or `:map <C-1> <C-6>` to '.vimrc', but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you use vim in iTerm 2, try to map control-1 to `0x1e` (`C-^`).

[image]

Comment: I add ':map <c-1> 0x1e' to '.vimrc', and it doesn't work.